# Wrap is not working on dynamically loaded element. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, dom, jquery-wrap

The `wrap();` works well on its own, but when it is called after the `load();`, it doesn't.

What could be done to make it work? I tried to put the `wrap();` code inside a separate .js file, but that didn't work. I also tried to load the `wrap();` inside: `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` and then place it inside the footer of the html, which didn't solve the problem either.

Here is my code:

```js
$('.page-id-202 #partner, .page-id-201 #partner').load('https://webhelytervezo.hu/ #gallery-1');
     $(".gallery-item").each(function() {
     $(this).wrap($("<a/>").attr("href", "http://" + $(".gallery-caption", this).text().trim()));
     $("#gallery-1 a").attr('target','_blank');
});
```

```css
figcaption{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-9 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-full"><figure class="gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
                <img width="200" height="74" src="https://webhelytervezo.hu/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/cup_revolution_logo.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" loading="lazy" aria-describedby="gallery-1-49">
            </div>
                <figcaption class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-49">
                www.web.cuprevolution.eu
                </figcaption></figure><figure class="gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
                <img width="200" height="74" src="https://webhelytervezo.hu/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/areklam.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" loading="lazy" aria-describedby="gallery-1-39">
            </div>
                <figcaption class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-39">
                www.areklam.hu
                </figcaption></figure><figure class="gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
                <img width="200" height="74" src="https://webhelytervezo.hu/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/coca_cola.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" loading="lazy" aria-describedby="gallery-1-48">
            </div>
                <figcaption class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-48">
                www.coca-cola.hu
                </figcaption></figure><figure class="gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
                <img width="200" height="74" src="https://webhelytervezo.hu/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/arkad.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" loading="lazy" aria-describedby="gallery-1-40">
            </div>
                <figcaption class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-40">
                www.arkad.hu
                </figcaption></figure><figure class="gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
                <img width="200" height="74" src="https://webhelytervezo.hu/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/besttv.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" loading="lazy" aria-describedby="gallery-1-41">
            </div>
                <figcaption class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-41">
                www.besttv.hu
                </figcaption></figure> 
        </div>
```

**Edit 1# & 2#:**

I need to wrap each `.gallery-item`s of the `#gallery-1` after it loaded from https://webhelytervezo.hu/ into the `#partner` div of page with the `.page-id-202` class (https://webhelytervezo.hu/en/) and the page with the class `.page-id-201` (https://webhelytervezo.hu/en/). The code works only on the main page (where the content is not loaded but there without needed to be loaded).

**Edit 3#**

Now the code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
$('.page-id-202 #partner, .page-id-201 #partner').load('https://webhelytervezo.hu/ #gallery-1', function(){
      $(".gallery-item").each(function() {
          $(this).wrap($("<a/>").attr("href", "http://" + $(".gallery-caption", this).text().trim()));
          $("#gallery-1 a").attr('target','_blank');
     })
});
  $(".gallery-item").each(function() {
          $(this).wrap($("<a/>").attr("href", "http://" + $(".gallery-caption", this).text().trim()));
          $("#gallery-1 a").attr('target','_blank');
     })
      });
```

How can I simplify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load is asynchronous function. Put your code inside callback function of the load method.

```
$('.page-id-202 #partner, .page-id-201 #partner').load('https://webhelytervezo.hu/ #gallery-1', function(){
      $(".gallery-item").each(function() {
          $(this).wrap($("<a/>").attr("href", "http://" + $(".gallery-caption", this).text().trim()));
          $("#gallery-1 a").attr('target','_blank');
     })   
})
```

Comment: Well yes, this should the right answer, but it doesn't work. Please, take a look at the site [here](https://webhelytervezo.hu/en/)

Comment: If you go there and look at the source code: view-source:https://webhelytervezo.hu/en/ you can see there is no id="gallery-1" element sou you won't we able to load it. I guess they load it via js.

Comment: True that it's loaded via JS.

Comment: It is here though https://webhelytervezo.hu . It should work...

Comment: The closing bracket was missing.     `$('.page-id-202 #partner, .page-id-201 #partner').load('https://webhelytervezo.hu/ #gallery-1', function(){
      $(".gallery-item").each(function() {
          $(this).wrap($("<a/>").attr("href", "http://" + $(".gallery-caption", this).text().trim()));
          $("#gallery-1 a").attr('target','_blank');
      })
});`

Comment: @iorgu Ok, I edited the answer so it is working.

Comment: Yes, it does work. Many thanks.

Comment: @iorgu I'll give you final advice. Use VScode or some other good code editor/IDE. If you used it you'd have seen immediately there is a missing bracket. I missed it here in wysiwyg editor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it around the `img` tag instead of its predecessor:

```js
$('.page-id-202 #partner, .page-id-201 #partner').load('https://webhelytervezo.hu/ #gallery-1');
$(".gallery-item .gallery-icon img").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap($("<a/>").attr("href", "http://" + $(".gallery-caption", this.parentNode.parentNode).text().trim()));
    $("#gallery-1 a").attr('target','_blank');
});
```

```css
figcaption{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-9 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-full"><figure class="gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
                <img width="200" height="74" src="https://webhelytervezo.hu/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/cup_revolution_logo.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" loading="lazy" aria-describedby="gallery-1-49">
            </div>
                <figcaption class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-49">
                www.web.cuprevolution.eu
                </figcaption></figure><figure class="gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
                <img width="200" height="74" src="https://webhelytervezo.hu/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/areklam.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" loading="lazy" aria-describedby="gallery-1-39">
            </div>
                <figcaption class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-39">
                www.areklam.hu
                </figcaption></figure><figure class="gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
                <img width="200" height="74" src="https://webhelytervezo.hu/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/coca_cola.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" loading="lazy" aria-describedby="gallery-1-48">
            </div>
                <figcaption class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-48">
                www.coca-cola.hu
                </figcaption></figure><figure class="gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
                <img width="200" height="74" src="https://webhelytervezo.hu/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/arkad.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" loading="lazy" aria-describedby="gallery-1-40">
            </div>
                <figcaption class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-40">
                www.arkad.hu
                </figcaption></figure><figure class="gallery-item">
            <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
                <img width="200" height="74" src="https://webhelytervezo.hu/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/besttv.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" loading="lazy" aria-describedby="gallery-1-41">
            </div>
                <figcaption class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-41">
                www.besttv.hu
                </figcaption></figure> 
        </div>
```

Comment: No, this is not the case. I've edited the question in hope for better understanding.

Comment: @iorgu, so when webhelytervező is loaded, some new items may appear and those are not properly wrapped? In my snippet an anchor was successfully wrapped around reklám and it actually works even from the snippet if I remove the target attribute.

Comment: @Lajos_Arpad No and yes. 
I would like to load the `#gallery-1` div into the `#partner` div of the addressed pages (what is working well) and **then** apply the wrapping code to this loaded part at the webhelytervezo.hu/en and /de.

Comment: @Lajos_Árpád the wrapping code has no flaw, it works at the main page where the #gallery-1 div is and not loaded dynamically, but on webhelytervezo.hu/en is the problem where the #gallery-1 has to be fetched from the main site.

Comment: @iorgu understood. So you have some containers which you will with `$('.page-id-202 #partner, .page-id-201 #partner').load()`, but it is unclear to me where those contents are defined and what you get from webhelytervező.

Comment: @Lajos_Árpád the `.page-id-201 #partner` is on the https://webhelytervezo.hu/en/ page and `.page-id-202 #partner` is on the https://webhelytervezo.hu/de/ page. I fetch the `#gallery-1` div from the https://webhelytervezo.hu/ (main site).

Comment: @iorgu so the snippet that you have in the question has the structure fetched from that source and if you run the `$(".gallery-item").each(function() {...})` code after the fetch completed in your Dev Tools console, then it works. But when you have the same code just below the call to the `load` function, then it does not work. If this is the scenario, then I know what the issue is and what should be the solution. So, can you confirm that the issue is well understood?

Comment: Árpád, the answer that @digitalniweb gave is the solution. It works now... he only missed a closing bracket from his code.

Comment: @iorgu excellent. I'm glad that the problem was resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, dear Árpád.

Comment: Your answer was relevant. I only realized this after I applied the main problem's solution. The wrapping is better on the `img` tag, and for that I also had to use it with the `this.parentNode.parentNode` selector - as you wrote it.

Comment: @iorgu thanks for letting me know. It is important that it works now. Such wrapping is less prone to structural changes and is a more stable approach to cope with this kind of requirements, at least according to my experience. It is less likely that you would wrap other items around the inner tag, but inside the wrapping tag than adding a tag between a previous and a next.